# Set the standard values based on condition

Tags: sitecore, rules

I have 2 items: "Collection" and "Category". Both of them use the same `template A` which has field `IsCollapse`. When I create any new collection it should have the default value of `true` and for category it should have `false`. I cannot create a separate template for each of them as the website has lots of business data for both items. Is there any way other than writing custom code to have some kind of rule in Sitecore to set different values for the same field?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to built this functionality from scratch, I would recommend creating a base template with the field `IsCollapse`. Templates `Collection` and `Category` would inherit from the base template and each template would have its own `__Standard Values` and the default value for `IsCollapse` field.

This is the ideal solution, however, as you already have a template and a lot of existing data and business logic around it, it is possible to use **[Branch Templates](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/branch-templates.html)** to achieve similar results.

You can create two separate branch templates based on the same `Template A`: Collection and Category. Each branch template will have its own `$name` item where you can specify default values for the `IsCollapse` field:

[image: Branch templates]

Then you can configure insert options to use branch templates `Collection` and `Category` instead of corresponding data templates:
[image: Insert options dialogue]